# OWL Carousel Slider causing other javascript stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have just installed the OWL Carousel script.

After installation i have noticed javascript stopped working at the bottom of page where Featured Products and Best Seller Carousel are.

the owl carousel works fine and you can see seperate code or example here. I can't add code here so i am adding the example link [please view the code by and example here](http://lazybeds.co.uk/owlmain.html)

After adding above code i have noticed javascript stopped working at the bottom of page where "Featured Products" and "Best Seller" Carousel are. Also layout is misbehaving. Please check here errors on live site [lazy beds](http://www.lazybeds.co.uk/)

anyone got idea. i have very basic knowledge of javascript and magento.

Comment: Any errors in `console`?

Comment: It appears that you forgot to include script file for jcarousel. hence the error 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jcarousel is not a function' in console

Comment: Please be sure to read the tag descriptions when posting your question.  This has nothing to do with [tag:owl], the Web Ontology Language.